# How to fix my useEffect or firestore functions to render the profile in the table

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get users which are in a collection and get their profile if filled from another collection in firestore. I am trying to render these in a table .

I am using react hooks . I have a userlist and setList to set it .
A temp userlist is populated first by querying the database. 
To the same temp userlist ,profile is added if profile is present in database.

The Users table is not rendered correctly . I have tried various combinations to set the list. I do not know how to run the useEffect after completion of the query.
I am sure this is a very common case and is there any glaring mistake that I am doing that you find? Pls suggest.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useAlert } from "react-alert";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { ContextOne } from "../ContextOne";

function Users() {
  let { state } = React.useContext(ContextOne);

  let initState = [];

  const [userlist, setList] = useState(initState);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  let userListener = null;
  useEffect(() => {

    const userListener = state.firebase.users().onSnapshot(
      snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.size) {
          let users_temp = [];
          snapshot.forEach(doc =>
            users_temp.push({ ...doc.data(), uid: doc.id })
          );

          //after users, get if users have a filled profile .get the profile.
          users_temp.forEach(doc =>
            state.firebase
              .profile(doc.uid)
              .get()
              .then(snapshot => {
                if (snapshot.data()) {
                  doc.profile = JSON.stringify(snapshot.data());
                }
              })
          );


          setList(users_temp);

          setLoading(false);
        } else {
          setLoading(false);
        }
      },
      err => {
        console.log(`Encountered error: ${err}`);
      }
    );

    return () => userListener();

  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="container">
     {<h1>{loading} </h1>}
      {loading && <div>Loading ...</div>}
      {!loading && userlist.length == 0 && <div>There are no users ...</div>}
      {!loading && <><h4>USERS</h4>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Created</td>
            <td>Profile</td>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {userlist.map(usr => (
            <tr key={usr.uid}>
              <td>{usr.username}</td>
              <td>{usr.email}</td>
              <td>{JSON.stringify(usr.created)}</td>
              <td>{usr.profile ? usr.profile :null}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table></>}
    </div>
  );
}
export default Users;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking an asynchronous `firebase` function which returns a promise inside the `forEach` loop in your effect. Hence the loop will not wait for promise to resolve and will execute `setList(users_temp);` much before.

Try:

```
const userPromises = users_temp.map(doc =>
  state.firebase.profile(doc.uid).get()
);

Promise.all(userPromises).then(snapshots => {
  snapshots.forEach((snapshot, index) => {
    if (snapshot && snapshot.data()) {
      users_temp[index].profile = JSON.stringify(snapshot.data());
    }
  });
  setList(users_temp);
});
```

And remove the `setList(users_temp)` at the end of your effect.

Comment: Thanks Easwar! I have tried this as well. What I see , is that the array is showing me all the users and the profile when I console.log .But the names and emails are rendered but the profile is not rendered. It is wierd.

Comment: What does a `profile` entry look like ? Could you paste one user entry from the array, right before `setList(users_temp);` is called ?

Comment: profile entry is a object with name value pairs. With the async code in as well, the setlist is executed first . I use console log just before setting list and at the time of setting profile .I get the setlist print first.and then the profile .So I tried adding setList

Comment: Ideally it should work. Have updated with an alternative answer. Please check.

Comment: Thanks Easwar for responding .I have finally found that somehow I have to rerender after profile is back.Though the profile is shown in the arrays when printing them. I setup another state variable and updated it after profile is stored.That way the re-rendering worked. I am sure something is amiss..I wil check this updated solution of yours as well.Thanks again!